# Error in rasterToPolygon trying to get several coverage layers

Tags: raster, r, rasterization

I have a very strange problem:

I am trying to get a raster with coverage from 0 to 1 in each cell for types of vegetation, I started with a raster of vegetation type, but I needed a raster with 12 times less resolution, here's my code

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

#Load raster
birds<- readGDAL("C:/Users/corcoranbarriosd/Documents/new_bats/Rnew_bats/Birds/2007_Raster.img")
birds <- raster(birds)

#transform raster to a resolution 12 times lower
ra <- aggregate(birds, fact= 17, expand = FALSE)

#get a layer of coverage of agroforest, which comprises cells type 0, 11, 13 and 4
AgroFo <- rasterToPolygons(birds, fun=function(x){x == 0| x == 11 | x == 13 | x == 14})
AgroFo <-rasterize(AgroFo, ra, getCover = TRUE)

#tranform it to a scale of 0 to 1    
AgroFo <- (AgroFo/100)

SecVec <- rasterToPolygons(birds, fun=function(x){x == 2 | x == 3| x == 8 })
SecVec <-rasterize(SecVec, ra, getCover = TRUE)
SecVec <- (SecVec/100)

#do it again for other types of veg
upland <- rasterToPolygons(birds, fun=function(x){x == 4 | x == 5 | x == 10 | x == 16})
upland <-rasterize(upland, ra, getCover = TRUE)
upland <- (upland/100)

wetland <- rasterToPolygons(birds, fun=function(x){x == 1 | x == 6 | x == 7 | x == 12})
wetland <-rasterize(wetland, ra, getCover = TRUE)
wetland <- (wetland/100)
```

It al goes well for AgroFo and for SecVec, but I get mistakes in Upland and getland in the step of rasterToPolygons.

This is the message i get:

Error in .Call(Polygons_c, srl, ID) :promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?Error during wrapup: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

I find it very weird, since the two first layers work fine, and the last two fail.

let me know of any clarification I can make to make my problem clearer

Comment: Fwiw, why re-rasterize? Looks like you could do this without rasterToPolygons

Comment: I thought there should be a way for it, how would you so it @mdsumner ? not asking you to give me the code, but adding a function "fun" to aggregate? I cant think of one

Comment: Don't do it in the function, just do it to the raster: "x <- AgroFo; x == 0| x == 11 | x == 13 | x == 14"

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner, I guess after that I can calculate the cover from that. You should write this in the answers so that I can credit you with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using @mdsumner suggestions plus some tweaks:

As suggested by mdsumner I used calc to get which values where of the values I needed, however this only gave me a 0 or 1 value, and I needed a 0 to 1 continuous landcover area type of thing, so then I used aggregate, and just selected how coarser my raster would be. It worked just as I needed with half the needed time.

```
#get 0 or 1 value
AgroFo <- calc(birds, fun=function(x){x == 0| x == 11 | x == 13 | x == 14})
#Get 0 to 1 value in lower resolution
AgroFo <- aggregate(AgroFo, fact= 17, expand = FALSE)

SecVec <- calc(birds, fun=function(x){x == 2 | x == 3| x == 8 })
SecVec <- aggregate(SecVec, fact= 17, expand = FALSE)

upland <- calc(birds, fun=function(x){x == 4 | x == 5 | x == 10 | x == 16})
upland <- aggregate(upland, fact= 17, expand = FALSE)

wetland <- calc(birds, fun=function(x){x == 1 | x == 6 | x == 7 | x == 12})
wetland <- aggregate(wetland, fact= 17, expand = FALSE)

BirdStack <- stack(AgroFo, SecVec, upland, wetland)
```